# Ударение в названии городов

Tags: фонетика

Правильно говорить не "в КерчИ", а "в КЕрчи". Но почему тогда говорят "в ПермИ", "в ТверИ"? Или это неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@cat](/users/111/cat)](/users/111/cat) абсолютно прав, потому что нормативным является вариант не "в КерчИ", а "в КЕрчи" (Словарь имен собственных на Грамоте.ру). И ударение "в ПермИ", "в ТверИ" тоже правильное. На вопрос "ПОЧЕМУ?" ответить не берусь. Так сложилось. Кроме того, думается, что под влиянием вариантов "в ПермИ" и "в ТверИ" вариант "в КерчИ", возможно, тоже со временем станет нормативным. Но пока правильным признается "в КЕрчи".

Что касается Ляписов, то они с языком обращаются очень вольно. Помните такую песенку еще "Крамбамбулі" : "Панаехала гасцей з іншаземных абласцей. Не, няправільна! гасцёў з іншаземных абласцёў"?:-)) [здесь](http://video.i.ua/user/478848/6969/110719/)

Answer (score -1):

Правильно говорить *"в Керчи́"* (даже песня такая у Ляписа Трубецкого была), вас явно обманули, когда сказали, что правильный другой вариант. Также верно *"в Перми́"* и в *"в Твери́"*

Comment: Правильно — в КЕрчи! Я 25 лет живу в Крыму и знаю точно, так что, боюсь, обманули Вас, а не автора вопроса)))